# proftpd sftp CentOS permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, sftp, proftpd

I would like configure a server SFTP on CentOs. I've tested on Ubuntu server and it works very well!

It seems that the location of users and the server have great importance.

I create a folder `/sftp` in `/` and a user bob :

```
mkdir /sftp
chmod 777 /sftp
adduser --home /sftp bob
```

When I connect bob to the sftp server, and I use `ls`, I have the message "permission denied":

```
sftp -P 2222 bob@x.x.x.x 
sftp>ls
remote readdir("/") : Permission denied
```

But know, if I change the location of the user bob in `/etc/passwd`, it Work !

```
chmod 777 /etc
nano /etc/passwd
bob:x:5000:99::/sftp:/bin/bash ---> bob:x:5000:99::/etc:/bin/bash
service proftpd restart

# On client
sftp -P 2222 bob@x.x.x.x 
sftp>ls
files ...
```

So I can not create my server outside of `/etc`, **Why?** I have tested on different version of proftpd.

Because I noticed on my Ubuntu server that works, if I place `/sftp` in `/etc` there are problems right to `put` command, but if I place `/sftp` in the root 'put' works well.

My file proftpd.conf is the basic configuration :

```
## basic config ...

SFTPEngine         on
Port               2222

SFTPLog            /var/log/proftpd/sftp.log
TransferLog        /var/log/proftpd/sftp-xferlog

# Host Keys
SFTPHostKey        /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
SFTPHostKey        /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key

# Auth methods
SFTPAuthMethods    password
AuthUserFile       /etc/proftpd/sftp.passwd

# SFTP specific configuration
DefaultRoot        ~
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of the question you asked before this, [PROFTPD SFTP permission denied centos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341999/proftpd-sftp-permission-denied-centos)? Your self-answer is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found! The security service CentOS of restricts access to some directory. So just to disable.

```
nano  /etc/selinux/config
SELINUX=disabled
#reboot system
```

Comment: Disabling security is a "workaround" not a solution.